# Defining entities in nestjs graphql code first approach with custom field results in error

Tags: graphql, nestjs, code-first

I am using NestJs along with GraphQL with code-first approach as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start). It works correctly till the time I have to use a custom field in an entity which is an array of objects.

```
@InputType('FormAnswerTaskDataInput')
@ObjectType()
export class FormAnswerTaskData extends BaseTaskData {
  @Field()
  id: string;

  @Field((type) => Int)
  order: number;

  @Field()
  title: string;

  @Field()
  widget: string;

  @Field((type) => Boolean)
  required: boolean;

  @Field((type) => [FormDataValue], { nullable: 'itemsAndList' })
  values: FormDataValue[];
}

@InputType()
class FormDataValue {
  @Field()
  value: string;
}
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot determine a GraphQL output type for the "values". Make sure your class is decorated with an appropriate decorator.
```

This error is only thrown when I add the line

```
  @Field((type) => [FormDataValue], { nullable: 'itemsAndList' })
  values: FormDataValue[];
```

If I use the code without the above line, then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh this looks familiar. I had got a similar error in my project.
Try adding a `@ObjectType()` decorator on your `FormDataValue` class.